# Why when starting backgroundworker the number of files in the list is not the same number of reporting files?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When adding images i'm adding them to a List and also updating a label:

```
private void Add_Files_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            openFileDialog.Filter = "All Images Files (*.png;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.tiff;*.tif)|*.png;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.tiff;*.tif" +
            "|PNG Portable Network Graphics (*.png)|*.png" +
            "|JPEG File Interchange Format (*.jpg *.jpeg *jfif)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jfif" +
            "|BMP Windows Bitmap (*.bmp)|*.bmp" +
            "|TIF Tagged Imaged File Format (*.tif *.tiff)|*.tif;*.tiff" +
            "|GIF Graphics Interchange Format (*.gif)|*.gif";

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (string filename in openFileDialog.FileNames)
                {
                    directories.Add(filename);
                    listView.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename));
                    i++;
                    label2.Content = i.ToString();
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                    Thread.Sleep(3);
                }
            }
        }
```

For example now in the List directories there are 46 files and also label2 show 46.

Now i click on start:

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (listView.Items.Count > 0)
                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

And in the dowork event i'm reporting both the percentages and the number of files during the process:

```
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < directories.Count; i++)
            {
                BitmapImage imagetosave = ResizeImage(directories[i]);
                Save(imagetosave, saveDirectory);

                int percents = ((i + 1) * 100) / directories.Count;
                worker.ReportProgress(percents, i);              
            }
        }
```

And in the progresschanged event:

```
private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            label.Content = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
            label2.Content = e.UserState;
            listView.Items.RemoveAt((int)e.UserState);
            listView.Items.Insert((int)e.UserState, "Resized and saved");
        }
```

In the end of the process label2 will show 45 and not 46.
It should show how many files have been processed.

In general i want to make the numbers go from high to low for example from to 46 to 0. Now i'm just showing first how many files the user added and then how many files have been processed but it's showing 45 instead 46.

Comment: As your `for (int i = 0; i < directories.Count; i++)` loops starts with `0` to `45` and not `46` because of `i < directories.Count`, you are getting wrong count in `worker.ReportProgress(percents, i);` So you gotta change it to `i <= directories.Count`.

Comment: Are you sure this is a windows forms app? It seems to me you are mixing WPF with Winforms.

Comment: don't use `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();` ......instead use a backgroundworker for that loop as well.

Comment: Since you are reporting `percents` based on `i + 1`, it only makes sense you would pass `i + 1` to the `ReportProgress()` method as well. You have a trivial off-by-one error.

Comment: @o_O: _"you gotta change it to `i <= directories.Count`"_ -- that's not going to work at all. Simply executing the loop 47 times instead of 46 will result in an `IndexOutOfRangeException` when `directories[i]` is evaluated.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yes u are absolutely correct. What I meant is what I said, but forgot to add this: `for (int i = 1; i <= directories.Count; i++)` or else `worker.ReportProgress(percents, i + 1);`

Comment: @PeterDuniho but if i change the in the ReportProgress to + 1 too like: worker.ReportProgress(percents, (i + 1)); then i'm getting exception in the progresschanged event on listView.Items.RemoveAt((int)e.UserState); out of range exception since there are 36 items in listView and it's reporting to 36. (For example 36 items).

Comment: Yes, you'd need to fix _all_ of the code. If you prefer, just add `1` before assigning to `label2.Content`. Whatever. It's not rocket science. If you can't figure it out, fix your question so it includes a good [mcve], so no one has to waste time coming up with something just to guess whether they have an actual answer or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i'm just showing first how many files the user added and then how many files have been processed but it's showing 45 instead 46.

That's because you pass `i` as the `userState` to the `ReportProgress` method. It should be `i + 1`:

```
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < directories.Count; i++)
    {
        BitmapImage imagetosave = ResizeImage(directories[i]);
        Save(imagetosave, saveDirectory);
        int x = i + 1;
        int percents = (x * 100) / directories.Count;
        worker.ReportProgress(percents, x);
    }
}
```

> In general i want to make the numbers go from high to low for example from to 46 to 0

Pass in `directories.Count - (i + 1)` then:

```
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < directories.Count; i++)
    {
        ...
        int x = i + 1;
        worker.ReportProgress(percents, directories.Count - x);
    }
}
```